# Disable UnitOfWork project wide in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

In [ASP.NET Boilerplate](http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work) we can disable `UnitOfWork` on method a level with attribute `[UnitOfWork(IsDisabled = true)]`.

Is there a way to completely disable UoW interceptor throughout all the application and just rely on `IUnitOfWorkManager`?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable transaction in your module.

```
Configuration.UnitOfWork.Scope = TransactionScopeOption.Suppress;
```